# Worldguard problem in guard action

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-worldguard

I'm running a Minecraft PvP server.
But concerning only "guard", there is a problem.

When non-OP players try to guard action by right clicking and holding sword, the player receives worldguard message "Hey! Sorry, but you can't use that here." .
However, damage is successfully reduced by guarding.

I tried so many things: change "passthrough" to "allow", cancel right click event using "Skript", asking google...
But they didn't work at all, so it is shown.

How can I disable the message?

Answer (score 1):

Flag determining the use of things that can do this is `interact`, which denies all interaction with blocks. Therefore if you right click and the flag is in play, it won't allow you to right click the block and tells you the message. So the right-click interaction with block you looking at will be denied, not the holding of sword in defensive maneuver (therefore you can see that defense was succesful).
However that shall not probably pop up when you aim with the sword into the air, but you did not mentioned if it is all the times or so.

So you need to use

```
/region flag <name of region> interact allow
```

However it will allow all interact actions , such as chest opening, levers, etc, if you don't deny them separately (flags like `use`, `chest-access` etc).

For more information, here is the actualized manual: http://docs.enginehub.org/manual/worldguard/latest/regions/flags/